# No overload matches this call - React + MUI + tsx

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tsx

**Use Case:** I am looking to build a `<Box/>` component that has a `datacy` attribute, with Material UI, React and tsx.

**Error:** tsx is throwing the error `No overload matches this call`.

```
<Box datacy="jobListing" padding={2} display={"flex"} alignItems={"center"}>
```

Whilst I know this is because of the `datacy` attribute, I need it to write tests with.

How can I change the code to ensure tsx does not look at this attribute as an error? I'll need, ideally, a global solution to reduce duplication.

**Full Error:**

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { component: ElementType<any>; } & SystemProps<Theme> & { align?: "right" | "left" | "center" | "inherit" | "justify"; children?: ReactNode; ... 6 more ...; variantMapping?: Partial<...>; } & CommonProps & Omit<...>): Element', gave the following error.
    Property 'component' is missing in type '{ children: string; datacy: string; variant: "h6"; fontWeight: number; }' but required in type '{ component: ElementType<any>; }'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: DefaultComponentProps<TypographyTypeMap<{}, "span">>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: string; datacy: string; variant: "h6"; fontWeight: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SystemProps<Theme> & { align?: "right" | "left" | "center" | "inherit" | "justify"; children?: ReactNode; ... 6 more ...; variantMapping?: Partial<...>; } & CommonProps & Omit<...>'.
      Property 'datacy' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SystemProps<Theme> & { align?: "right" | "left" | "center" | "inherit" | "justify"; children?: ReactNode; ... 6 more ...; variantMapping?: Partial<...>; } & CommonProps & Omit<...>'.ts(2769)
OverridableComponent.d.ts(21, 7): 'component' is declared here.
```

Comment: There is usually some additional information after `No overload matches this call`

Comment: Added full error

Comment: Did you mean `data-cy`?

Comment: I did not mean `data-cy`. I meant `datacy`.

Comment: I guess that you are using cypress https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#How-It-Works There is no `datacy` attribute on any element, but you can add `data-cy` to any element. If you want to use `datacy` instead you would have to change elements definitions in `d.ts` files. But adding `datacy` will make your html invalid

Comment: You can probably use module augmentation to add the datacy prop to all your MUI components. I don't have an example ready for you at the moment but here is an example on MUI about extending their theme interfaces: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/#adding-new-colors